# How to properly position a view with AnimatedCircularProgress in React Native

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I'm using a module called [react-native-circular-progress](https://github.com/bgryszko/react-native-circular-progress)
but I could not properly place a View (consists of stats) inside the circle.

According to the author:
*You can also define a function, that'll receive current progress and for example, display it inside the circle:*

```
<AnimatedCircularProgress
  size={200}
  width={3}
  fill={this.state.fill}
  tintColor="#00e0ff"
  backgroundColor="#3d5875">
  {
    (fill) => (
      <Text style={styles.points}>
        { this.state.fill }
      </Text>
    )
  }
</AnimatedCircularProgress>
```

This is the snippet of how the author positions the text inside a circle, which will not be appropriate when it comes to the screen of different sizes.

```
points: {
  backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  position: 'absolute',
  top: 72,
  left: 56,
  width: 90,
  textAlign: 'center',
  color: '#7591af',
  fontSize: 50,
  fontWeight: "100"
},
```

This is my code so far, I designed my circle size to be as dynamic as possible when it comes to difference screen sizes.

```
<View tabLabel="Progress" style={styles.progress}>
    <View style={styles.progressView}>
        <AnimatedCircularProgress
            size={0.8 * deviceWidth}
            width={0.08 * deviceWidth}
            fill={this.state.progressSliderValue}
            tintColor="#1A81FF"
            backgroundColor="#EBEBF1"
        ></AnimatedCircularProgress>
    </View>

    <View style={styles.progressViewText}>
        <Text style={styles.mileageText}>
            {this.state.patientMileageStatic}
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.kmText}>KM</Text>
        <Text style={styles.targetText}>
            Target: {this.state.patientTarget} km
        </Text>
    </View>

    <View style={styles.sosButtonWrapper}>
        <TouchableHighlight
            underlayColor="gray"
            onPress={this.sosPressed}
            style={styles.sosButton}
        >
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>SOS</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
    </View>
</View>
```

[image: My Work]

So I am trying to place the green box inside my circle, in a way that it relatives to the circle, and always to be centered.

Is there any workaround? The docs don't provide enough explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, I just changed the top and left values in styles.point to make it central. Try to change the values there. [Click this to see the snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBp5j.png)